# 500 internal server error in spring mvc 3 controller response for ajax call

Tags: java, spring-mvc

my code gives 500 error when I have the following code. It sends a jason response to an ajax call.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/savecourse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Object saveLecturer(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "course") Course course,
        BindingResult result) {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<ObjectError> results = result.getAllErrors();
        for (ObjectError objectError : results) {
            System.out.println(objectError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        response.put("message", "Could not add the Course to the system.");
    } else {
        try {
            course.setId(courseDao.saveCourse(course));//returns the id
            response.put("course", course);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

But when I create a new object and copy the parameters to the other object, it works fine. The second method(Not a good method of course) works well. All the parameters in the request object are set to the cse object as well.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/savecourse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Object saveLecturer(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "course") Course course,
        BindingResult result) {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<ObjectError> results = result.getAllErrors();
        for (ObjectError objectError : results) {
            System.out.println(objectError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        response.put("message", "Could not add the Course to the system.");
    } else {
        try {
            course.setId(courseDao.saveCourse(course));//returns the id
            Course cse = new Course();
            cse.setId(course.getId());
            cse.setCourseName(course.getCourseName());
            cse.setFee(course.getFee());
            Lecturer lec = new Lecturer();
            lec.setId(course.getLecturer().getId());
            lec.setFirstName(course.getLecturer().getFirstName());
            lec.setLastName(course.getLecturer().getLastName());
            cse.setLecturer(lec);
            cse.setGrade(course.getGrade());
            response.put("course", cse);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong in the first method? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 500 Error is coming because your Spring MVC controller is throwing some exception. Did you check the logs? Or did you try attaching a debugger to the code to see where it is failing?

Comment: Wild guess would be that the object serializer is trying to access something on the Course that's lazy loaded and you don't have an open session for your Managed instance of Course that you passed it, so it pukes.  The un-managed version that you created fresh doesn't care.  The actual server log should tell you the exception that caused the 500.